# RxJava Can subscribe() on an Observable.empty() call onComplete() before the onSubscribe() returns a Subscription causing a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, observable, rx-java

I am writing to logic that merges two Observables together so that I can make sure they both run together and complete a whole. To do this, I have used the `Observable.mergeDelayError()` as seen below. However, when I am writing my unit tests, sometimes, I get a `NullPointerException` when trying to call `mRefreshSubscription.unsubscribe()` where `mRefreshSubscription` is null.

Question:
Is it possible that the resulting merged Observable, because it can be double empty, proceed to call into `onComplete()` faster than `subscribe()` returns a subscription?

```
Observable observA = Observable.empty();
Observable observB = Observable.empty();

mRefreshSubscription = Observable.mergeDelayError(observA, observB)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(getRefreshObserver());

private Observer getRefreshObserver() {
    if (mRefreshObserver == null) {
        mRefreshObserver = new Observer() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                mRefreshSubscription.unsubscribe();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                mRefreshSubscription.unsubscribe();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Object o) {
                // do nothing
            }
        };
    }
    return mCleanAndAutoSubscriberObserver;
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `unsubscribe` from `onCompleted` and `onError` in the Observer? RxJava will call `unsubscribe` automatically once either of those events occur on the stream.

Comment: That's a good question. I shouldn't have to you're right because as you said, when those methods are called, unsubscribe would have been called.